# Making a table in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have similar code in PHP:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Create table
$sql="CREATE TABLE Workers
(
PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(PID),
Name VARCHAR(30),
)";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    echo "Table persons created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

I need to add these columns: name, birthdate, ID code, active/noactive, contactinformation (e-mail, phone, address), self-introduction (in three languages), work experience (in three languages), education (in three languages), when and who created, when and who modified.

How can I add three different things in one column?

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say you don't know how to add three different things in one column, the columns you are reffering to are self introduciton and other columns in three languages.  You should not have one column that holds the same information in three languages.  If all three languages are required, I would create three columns, SelfIntroductionEnglish, SelfIntroductionRussian, etc...  If only one of the languages is required for any record, I recomend a seperate SelfIntroduction talbe.  It would have a foreign key to your main table, a flag column that stores the language of the column, and a third column that holds the self introduciton in the specified language.  Then you could easily check if a Worker has an introduction in English, and if so grab it.

Comment: I think I get it now a little. Found this link: https://foundationdb.com/layers/sql/documentation/GettingStarted/employees.tutorial.html . It helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the last column in your CREATE TABLE query shouldn't have a comma after it.  You only do that when separating column names.

Also, as to adding things to one column, it's not realistic.  A good way to think of sql is like a really advanced version of a spreadsheet.  You shouldn't have more than one piece of information in any given cell.  You would need three columns, or some way to translate information from one column into another language.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that way?

```
    // Create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE workers
(
    PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(PID),
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
    id_code INT NOT NULL,
    activity INT NULL
)";

$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE contacts (
    FOREIGN KEY(PID),
    PRIMARY KEY(PID),
        email VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    phone INT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)";

$sql3 = "CREATE TABLE personality (
    FOREIGN KEY(lang),
    PRIMARY KEY(PID,lang),
    lang VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
        selfintroduction VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    workexperience VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    education VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)";
```

I don't know how to do that added and modified stuff.

Comment: Hmm. No it isn't so because only $sql is created. But mysqli_query allows only 3 inputs).